# RestAssured with Mockito: mock dao repository

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, mocking, rest-assured

I am trying to test my REST endpoints using `RestAssured` with mocking some of the service/repositories in the controller.

this is my test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@Transactional
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT, classes = {VedicaConfig.class})
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class RESTTest {
@LocalServerPort
    private int port;

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;

    @Mock
    MetaVersionDAO metaVersionDAO;

    @InjectMocks
    DocCtrl docCtrl;

    @Before
    public void contextLoads() {
        RestAssured.port = port;
        assertThat(mvc).isNotNull();

        // this must be called for the @Mock annotations above to be processed.
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        RestAssuredMockMvc.standaloneSetup(MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(docCtrl));
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldGetThumbnail() {
        String ver = "1.0";
        String uuid = "124-wqer-365-asdf";
        when(metaVersionDAO.getMetaByVersionUUID(ver, uuid)).thenReturn(new DocVersion());

        given()
                .when()
                .param("uuid", uuid)
                .param("versionVed", ver)
                .get(CTX_BASE + "/thumbnail")
                .then()
                .log().ifValidationFails()
                .statusCode(OK.value())
                .contentType(ContentType.BINARY);
    }

}
```

now, the REST endpoint itself is being hit correctly with supplied parameters. this endpoint has `DocCtrl` injected which uses `metaVersionDAO` instance in turn:

```
    public RawDocument getDocThumbnail(String uuid, String versionVed) throws Exception {
        DocVersion docVersion = metaVersionDAO.getMetaByVersionUUID(versionVed, uuid);
        InputStream inputStream = okmWebSrv.getOkmService().getContentByVersion(uuid, versionVed);
        String dataType = docVersion.getMetadata().getAdditionals().get(Vedantas.CONTENT_TYPE);
        ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(createPDFThumbnail(dataType, inputStream));

        RawDocument rawDocument = new RawDocument(bais, "qwer");
        return rawDocument;
    }
```

as you can see, I have tried to mock `metaVersionDAO` at the top of the `@Test` method so I expected it to return `new DocVersion()` as I set it to, but in this DAO the actual code is being called and it fails on entityManager which is null.

My question is why `metaVersionDAO.getMetaByVersionUUID` doesn't return my mocked object and what should I do to make it so?

spring-mock-mvc: 3.3.0
spring-boot: 2.1.2.RELEASE

Thanks!

Comment: Try annotating your dao as follows: `@MockBean MetaVersionDAO metaVersionDAO;`, removing your `@InjectMocks` annotation, and in your `@Before` method, create your `DocCtrl` instance and pass `metaVersionDAO` in the constructor (assuming you're using constructor injection).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

solved by changing `@Mock` for `@MockBean`.

so it is:

```
    @MockBean
    MetaVersionDAO metaVersionDAO;
```

everything else remains the same as in the post and it uses mocked instance.